# readonly attr is disabling jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have inputs where I activate the jQuery Datepicker to allow the user to select dates. They look like this: `<input type="text" id="from" name="from" value="'.$from.'" />`

Since users will be selecting these dates on their phones, I needed to disable the native keyboard, so I set these to readonly like this: `$("#from").attr("readonly",true);` Note that I also need them to be `readonly` because I have restrictions on dates and such.

While the above works just fine in desktop/laptop browsers, I am unable to select dates using my iPhone (Safari and Mercury tested). When I tap the input, nothing happens. See the site on mobile if needed: http://www.recordyouradventures.com/testsite

So is there something that I am missing because from what I thought, datepicker would override `readonly` just as it does on desktop browsers.

I have tried setting `type="date"` and `readonly="readonly"` in the HTML, both of which still leave the input locked to mobile phone.

Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: It seems that there is an issue with the compatibility of the mobile safari using jquery datepicker, Even triggering the show event $("#from").datepicker("show") doesn't let me select any date on the calendar try using the native type="date"

Comment: @EduardoQuintana interesting, I agree. Putting `type="date"` does change it. Removing the `readonly` will free up the ability to use the `type="date"` but this then does not take into account the restrictions I have on the date ranges.

Comment: You could use the max and min ranges on the inputs

Comment: Then on the change of from update the min attr of #to

Answer (score 2):

//You can force the datepicker become visible onclick of readonly textbox.

```
$('#text_field').click(function(){
    $(this).datepicker('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use readonly attribute in html tag itself.
like `<input type="text" id="from" name="from" value="'.$from.'" readOnly />`